# Akka Stream (Akka Http) - watchTermination is called before all elementa are consumed

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

I'm working on an async scala driver for neo4j (https://github.com/neotypes/neotypes) and trying to implement query result streaming for Akka Stream.

The type class for Akka Stream looks as follows:

```scala
  type Stream[T] = Source[T, Future[Unit]]

  def init[T](value: () => Future[Option[T]]): AkkaStream.Stream[T] =
    Source
      .repeat()
      .mapAsync[Option[T]](1)(_ => value())
      .takeWhile(_.isDefined)
      .map(_.get)
      .viaMat(Flow[T])((_, _) => Future.successful(()))
```

I also have the following completion hook:

```scala
  override def onComplete[T](s: AkkaStream.Stream[T])(f: => Future[Unit]): AkkaStream.Stream[T] =
    s.watchTermination() {
      (_, done) =>
        done.flatMap(_ => f)
    }
```

The main goal of the completion hook is to gracefully close the transaction after all elements are read. The code above works as expected when used with a simple `Sink` (working example https://github.com/neotypes/neotypes/blob/master/akka-stream/src/test/scala/neotypes/akkastreams/AkkaStreamSpec.scala), however when I try streaming result via Akka Http, `watchTermination` is called prematurely which makes the transaction being closed in the middle of the process.